# How do I make floated elements resize correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and everything I try fails to produce the result I am after.

So the setup is as follows

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="icon-holder">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png" class="icon"/>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-holder">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png" class="icon"/>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-holder">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png" class="icon"/>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-holder">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png" class="icon"/>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-holder">
            <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_square-128.png" class="icon"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.icon-holder {
    float:left;
    height:100%; 
    width:auto;
}

.container {
    height:100px;
}

.icon {
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:block;
}

.container-before {
    height:100px;
}

.container-after {
    height:20px;
}
```

Now the problem lies in that if I use javascript to resize the container I need the images to resize with it and have no spacing in between. I need a CSS solution that works, I know I can hack it with JS but thats not what I am trying to accomplish.

I have an example running at http://jsfiddle.net/twmxh/3/ of the whole issue with expected output.

### UPDATE

Just a bit more about the implementation. The `container` div is actually a toolbar with a resize handle. So the container is the only element I can apply the new height on.

Comment: It works in FireFox but not in Chrome

Comment: JS fiddle is action odd with this example. Run your example as-is, click your button to shrink the top icons, inspect element on any of the top icons, uncheck then recheck any css style and watch your icons change to what you want.

Comment: When I run your code as-is in chrome is works jsut as you expect it to. JSfiddle is working incorrectly for this.\

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this

```
$("#resize").click(function() {
  $('.container').height("20px"); 
  $('.container .icon').width("20px"); 
});
```

Comment: I have just added an update to the question stating the container div is the only thing that can be updated. Plus I added a new JSFiddle as animate is not what I am actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your CSS for the image size

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

i don't think heights and percentages behave well in most browsers

This is generally how you can define the size for a "responsive" image... whereas the width will always fit the size of the container, and the height will follow suit automagically.

edit your code so that the animation scales by width rather than by height.  see if that works.

Comment: I would set it to `width: auto;` and `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: This example is vertically responsive, not horizontally responsive like normal browser responsive design.

Comment: oh i see... in that case go with the above comment `max-width: 100%;`  that is how IE recognizes heigh in percentages.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be triggering some funny browser bugs - it works fine essentially in both Firefox and Chrome, but both screw up on the element resize in different ways. In IE10 your sample doesn't run at all.

However, for the intended result you shouldn't be using `animate` at all in these modern CSS3 days, just use CSS transitions instead, [like this example Fiddle solving your case to work in all current browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/6WBKu/).

Comment: The main issue I have is that I am not actually using animate that was the quickest way to show the issue. The container actually has a resizable handle on it which is controlled by the user.

Comment: Well the issue is most certainly in browser bugs right now - in Chrome you can 'fix' the issue by toggling a random CSS class off and on after your Fiddle has run. That means a Webkit bug. Firefox just resizes the containers once after the animation, which is also fundamentally wrong, and a Gecko bug. Trident doesn't run it at all, so I think that disqualifies your current approach for production usage  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the dynamically changed widths

```
clear:right;
```

this will refresh the container

heres a link

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)